# How can I retrieve the current roman, sans, and mono fonts in LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, lua

I am working on a LuaLaTeX package, and at one point I have to pass the full names of the three basic font families (roman, sans, mono) to another tool. I have found and checked that I can correctly do that for the *currently active* font, but that's not exactly what I need:

```
fonts.hashes.identifiers[font.current()].fullname
```

correctly produces, e.g. "Linux Libertine O", if that's what is currently used for typesetting. (I don't know if that's the correct or easiest way to get to that, so I'd be glad about simplifications.

However, as said I need also the font names defined with `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont`. From the documentation is looks like `font.id()` is my best bet, but so far I didn' have any luck.

**[Edit:]** When I say "font names" I mean the "family name" of the three fonts that are defined in the mandatory argument of the `\setXXXXfont` commands, ignoring any specification that can be done in the optional argument.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. \setmainfont doesn't define one specific font but a whole family with various shapes and weights.

Comment: Hm, it's difficult to update the question, as in the meantime I have realized that there is another, more fundamental issue for me to be solved (and that can't properly be mixed into this question: before dealing with the three roman/sans/mono fonts I need to know how to actually retrieve the font *family* from a Lua `font` object. AFAICS I can get `fullname` (which is pretty inconsistently used between font companies), `psname` and `name`, which is a concatenation of different information incluting the psname. But I don't see a way to get to the "family" yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a longer [discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/luatex@tug.org/msg06565.html) on the luaTeX mailing list and with the `fontspec` developer I found a working solution (although I find it somewhat awkward). The idea is activating the three font families one after another, capture them as "current", and wrap everything in a group. The trick is the use of `\edef`.

```
\begingroup
\rmfamily \edef\rmfamilyid{\fontid\font}%
\ssfamily \edef\ssfamilyid{\fontid\font}%
\ttfamily \edef\ttfamilyid{\fontid\font}%
\directlua{
    myfonts = { }
    myfonts.rm =
    fonts.hashes.identifiers[\rmfamilyid].shared.rawdata.metadata['familyname']
    myfonts.sf =
    fonts.hashes.identifiers[\ssfamilyid].shared.rawdata.metadata['familyname']
    myfonts.tt =
    fonts.hashes.identifiers[\ttfamilyid].shared.rawdata.metadata['familyname']
}%
\endgroup
```

After that the three family names are available in the `myfonts` Lua table.